# How to use goBack in react-native to goBack two screens one by one

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have 4 screens in my react application and i have used push method to go to each screen. When i go from A-->B-->C and press goBack on C it comes back to B. But when i press goBack on B it remains in the same screen. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What navigator are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you use stack navigator of react-navigation and keep your screen in that like below:
    `const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: HomeScreen,    // <----
        },
        Details: {
          screen: DetailsScreen, // <----
        },
     },
     {
       initialRouteName: 'Home',
      }
    );
    export default App extends React.Component {
        render() {
        /* In the root component we are rendering the app navigator */
        return <AppNavigator />;
      }
    }`

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).